# How can I implement iOS 7 calendar grid view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, calendar

I'm trying to implement grid table as in `iOS 7 Calendar app week view`. What should i use for it? I tried to use simple `UITableView` but I don't know how to make it `scroll vertically and horizontally` at the same time. May be there are some controls for this?

Comment: You may use UICollectionView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To tackle this issue you should use a `UICollectionView` and create your own `UICollectionViewLayout`.

[A brilliant article on custom `UICollectionViewLayouts` can be found here.](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/collection-view-layouts.html) In this article it specifically discussed a limited calendar layout which presents a week.